# SQL Select multiple value between brackets in a string

Tags: sql, string, merge, split

I have a SQL String with merge fields in string enclosed in brackets. 
I would like to extract only the merge fields.

**String**

```
Payment Plan of {{ExpectedAmount|11}}. Pay into {{BankName|4}} {{BankAccountNumber|11}} Code {{BankBranchCode|6}} use ref # {{AccountNumber|10}} send proof<br/>
```

Declare @String varChar(MAX) = 'select  Payment Plan of {{ExpectedAmount|11}}. Pay into {{BankName|4}} {{BankAccountNumber|11}} Code {{BankBranchCode|6}} use ref # {{AccountNumber|10}} send proof'
Select @String
Then how do I only get the values between the multiple {{***}}

**Return**

```
{{ExpectedAmount|11}}
{{BankName|4}}
{{BankAccountNumber|11}}
{{BankBranchCode|6}}
{{AccountNumber|10}}
```

Comment: What database do you use ?

Comment: you can use a regex like - `'/({{[a-z]+\|[0-9]+}})/i'` to match your strings and concat them as you like.

Comment: Database is SQL

Comment: SQL is not a database, it's a language which dialects a range of DBMSes use. What is your DBMS?

Comment: Hi Guys. TSQL from a SQL DB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MS sql server version based on its XML facilities.

```
declare @tbl table(
   col nvarchar(max)
);

insert @tbl(col)
values('Payment Plan of {{ExpectedAmount|11}}. Pay into {{BankName|4}} {{BankAccountNumber|11}} Code {{BankBranchCode|6}} use ref # {{AccountNumber|10}} send proof');

select t2.n.value ('.[1]', 'nvarchar(1000)') txt
from ( 
       select cast('<root>'+replace(replace(col, '{{','<elem>{{'),'}}','}}</elem>')+'</root>' as xml) x
       from @tbl
     ) t
cross apply t.x.nodes('/root/elem') t2(n);
```